# WinRT Xaml ListView cant collapse DataTemplate Rows

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, datatemplate

I have a listview that is using a DataTemplateSelector to determine which DataTemplate to use. The problem is that I have controls on my view that need to dynamically show and hide rows in the listview. The issue is that the DataTemplate automatically inserts ListViewItem for each row, even if I have all my content collapsed and just shows the empty row.

Is there a way to force collapse on a DataTemplate